# Free form selection using kinetic js and/or html5 canvas

Tags: html, image-processing, kineticjs

I am looking for some library that can allow my user to do free form selection from uploaded image  and get its co-ordinates . Each free form selection will be my one object. For example [image: Image example]

This will be my image, I **will select complete mat area free-form way and then copy its co-ordinates.**

If any other api is available,please tell.

NOTE : Here I am talking about free form selection **NOT RECTANGULAR** selection .
If you are not sure , you can look here 
 [here](http://instructionaldesigning.blogspot.in/2011/04/remove-background-in-powerpoint-using.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_select)

Comment: have a look http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E_NLei3vbtc/TbaD0h3X1qI/AAAAAAAAAFU/yFmLRKVwOhM/s320/2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ Added to answer based on questioner's comment ]**

What you want is edge detection--get ready for some seriously intense coding.

Here's what Wiki says about a common edge detection algorithm called "marching squares":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares.

A nice implimention of marching squares is in d3 (d3js.org).

http://code.google.com/p/testprogramming/source/browse/trunk/javascript/svg/d3/src/geom/contour.js?r=383

This implementation is nice because it lets you define what's included & what's excluded in determining your target selection.

You will need this ability because your selections are not as simple as isolating transparent vs non-transparent pixels.

For example, to isolate your cat you will first have to limit the search area to pixels near the cat.  You can do this using my original answer which makes a new image from a rectangular selection.

Then you must create an algorithm that includes the range of darker pixels as the cat and excludes the lighter pixels in the chair/floor/wall.

You will have to become an expert at isolation techniques.

**[ Original Answer ]**

Here's an html5 canvas demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Bc3uK/

[image]

And here's some annotated code for you to start learning from:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    // create a temporary canvas
    // used to clip the selected area from the whole image
    var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var isDown=false;

    var $stats=$("#stats");

    var cw,ch,startX,startY,mouseX,mouseY

    // load and draw the main image on the canvas
    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/selection.png";
    function start(){

        // size the canvas to the image size
        // and draw the image on the canvas
        cw=canvas.width=img.width;
        ch=canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        // listen for mouse events
        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
        $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // calculate the current mouse position
      // this is the start position of the drag
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // set a flag indicating we've started dragging
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // get the current mouse position
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // turn off the drag flag
      isDown=false;

      // calc the width/height of the selection
      var w=mouseX-startX;
      var h=mouseY-startY;

      // clip the selection and draw it to the temporary canvas
      // then create a new image from the selection
      // and add it to the page
      tempCanvas.width=w;
      tempCanvas.height=h;
      tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,startX,startY,w,h,0,0,w,h);
      var newImage=new Image();
      newImage.onload=function(){
          document.body.appendChild(newImage);
      }
      newImage.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();

    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // unset the drag flag
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){

      // if we're not dragging, just exit
      if(!isDown){return;}

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // calc the current mouse position
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // calc current width/height
      var w=mouseX-startX;
      var h=mouseY-startY;

      // display starting/ending drag points and current width/height
      $stats.text("x1/y1: "+startX+"/"+startY+", x2/y2: "+mouseX+"/"+mouseY+", width/height: "+w+"/"+h);

      // clear and redraw the canvas showing the current drag rectangle
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      ctx.strokeRect(startX,startY,w,h);

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id=stats>Drag mouse to make selection</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to have a free form selection please have a look here,http://instructionaldesigning.blogspot.in/2011/04/remove-background-in-powerpoint-using.html  like selecting cat only and its co-ordinates precisely.

Comment: What you want is edge detection.  See the addition to my answer for some links on learning and implementing edge detection.